# Getting Textarea Value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is driving me crazy - why doesn't my code work?

```
<a id="send-thoughts" href="">Click</a>
<textarea id="#message"></textarea>

            jQuery("a#send-thoughts").click(function() {
                var thought = jQuery("textarea#message").val();
                alert(thought);
            });
```

alerts undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/q5EXG/

Comment: Never do `$('a#send-thoughts')`, just do `$('#send-thoughts')`.  The performance implications of doing the former are substantial as jQuery will go out and get all of the anchors on the page rather than doing the fastest selector there is: getElementById.

Comment: just to add to this, html ids should be unique... so it's superfluous to add the `a` in your selector.  So remember, you can only have one `#send-thoughts` element on your page

Comment: +1 to you Brad, right on.  Also, an `href` attribute on an anchor tag should never be an empty string.  If you want no action to occur, set it as such: `<a href="#">click</a>` and then in your click event `return false;` at the end.

Comment: appreciate the tips, gents. however, for some reason, when I leave out the `a`, my jQuery no longer works...... ID's are unique, too.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you have `id="#message"`... should be `id="message"`

http://jsfiddle.net/q5EXG/1/

Comment: ok ok ok, you are correct here.... but that is a typo i made in writing the code on jsfiddle

Comment: instead of trying to explain what the issue is in this question, I'm just gonna mark your answer as correct and ask a new one. I appreciate your help!

Comment: what i mean to say is, yes, that was the error in the code that I posted.... but in my actual code on my site, that typo does not exist, yet the variable is still alerting as undefined... possibly due to a conflict with other code, etc. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: did you see my fiddle?  It clearly works.  Make sure that you only have one element with the ID `message`.

Comment: @brad see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708989/error-getting-textarea-value-with-jquery

Answer (score 14):

By using new version of jquery (1.8.2), I amend the current code like in this links
http://jsfiddle.net/q5EXG/97/

By using the same code, I just change from jQuery to '$'

```
<a id="send-thoughts" href="">Click</a>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>

$('#send-thoughts').click(function()
{ var thought = $('#message').val();
  alert(thought);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done at easily like as:

```
     <a id="send-thoughts" href="">Click</a>
     <textarea id="message"></textarea>

        $("a#send-thoughts").click(function() {
            var thought = $("#message").val();
            alert(thought);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

change id="#message" to id="message" on your textarea element.

and by the way, just use this:

```
$('#send-thoughts')
```

> remember that you should only use ID's once and you can use classes over and over.

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a id="send-thoughts" href="">Click</a>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<!--<textarea id="#message"></textarea>-->

            jQuery("a#send-thoughts").click(function() {
                //var thought = jQuery("textarea#message").val();
                var thought = $("#message").val();
                alert(thought);
            });
```