# Error getting textarea value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok, my last post was a failure, so let's try this again.

If you visit www.davekiss.com and click on the icon in the top right corner, you'll see a customized implementation of a jQuery slider. Click on the "Contact" button and fill out the textarea.

Basically, what I am trying to is save the value in that textarea to a javascript variable, but for some reason, that variable is undefined.

The code in question:

```
            jQuery("a#send-thoughts").click(function() {
                var thought = jQuery("textarea#message").val();
                alert(thought);

                /*jQuery.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "process.php",
                   data: "message=" + message,
                   success: function(msg){
                     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                   }
                });*/
            });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm betting you are looking for `.text()` but can you show the `HTML` too?  Might be helpful.

Comment: It is working. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/sVXf5/

Comment: right, i just experienced that myself - it works in a plain fiddle, but not in my live site environment.

Comment: Look over your HTML one last time: `<tr><td>Message: </td><td><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></td></tr>`.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong section. I'm not trying to get it from the contact page, rather, the second contact section that you can reach by clicking on the "Welcome, DK" icon in the far top right corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your textarea has a name of 'message', but not an id. Your selector is selecting based on an ID, but no such element exists. Either give the textarea the id of "message", or change your selector to find by name (former is probably preferred).

Comment: where are you seeing this? not true, textarea doesn't have a name, only an id of "message"

Comment: `<tr><td>Message: </td><td><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></td></tr>`.

Comment: Yes - see the HTML that Blender posted.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong section. I'm not trying to get it from the contact page, rather, the second contact section that you can reach by clicking on the "Welcome, DK" icon in the far top right corner.

Comment: I don't see any text area in that modal window

Comment: don't click on the green "contact" button..... click on the icon at the far top right that reads "welcome, dk" and you will see a different contact section if you click on the contact button which looks like an elevator button

Comment: odd, that textarea didn't appear for me before, it does now...  see my answer, i can only assume it has to do with your syntax error.

Comment: You have that textarea in your HTML twice. It looks like the second one is getting filled out, but since a selection by ID will only target the first one, that's why you are getting a blank alert.

Comment: One is under <li class="floor"> and one is under the <li class="floor pager"> (the last one).

Comment: Ah, sir, I believe you are correct. The plugin I am using duplicates the last slide to appear on top of the first, and the first slide to appear below the last.... I wonder how to avoid the conflict in this scenario

Comment: I ended up using `$(this).siblings()` to grab the closest textarea to what was clicked, and changed the ID's to classes. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `html()` instead of `val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it's `.text()`:

```
var thought = jQuery("textarea#message").text();
```

Comment: Yep, just what I suspected. You don't have an `id` on your textarea. Give it an `id`, preferably `id="message"` and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a syntax parse error on line 232.  You're missing a `)` to your append function.

Comment: can you post the entire line that you are referencing?

Comment: doens't seem to happen anymore, must have caught it mid, editing or something